# How to add line number to only a specific line in a file

Tags: c

I'm creating the inputs of a disease and information on it. The disease should have a number beside it but the remaining inputs should remain as is. How can i add the information to a file but have the disease number increment as it reads new inputs as the program closes?

I've tried using a variable to print the disease number as it goes, but i dont understand how to increment it.

```
void CreateNew(){

    int diseasenum=1;
    FILE*fptr;

    fptr = fopen("Lifeline Medical & Diagnostic Center.txt", "a+");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! There is no file to write to. Please Create a file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter the name of the disease you would like to give detail of: ");
    gets(Dissarray.Disease);

    if()
        fprintf(fptr,"%d\tDisease: %s\n\n",diseasenum,Dissarray.Disease);

    printf("\n");

    fflush(stdin);

    Dissarray.Lethality=0;

    printf("What is the Lethality of %s?\t(Answer in percentage. Sample:90 OR 12, etc)\n",Dissarray.Disease);
    if (scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Lethality)!= 1)
    {
      printf("This is not an appropriate number. Please enter appropriately.\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Lethality);
    }
    fprintf(fptr,"Lethality: %d\n",Dissarray.Lethality);
    printf("\n");

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("How is %s acquired. (Sample: Contagious Disease, STI, Hereditary)\n",Dissarray.Disease);
    gets(Dissarray.ContagionFactor);
    fprintf(fptr,"Contagion factor: %s\n",Dissarray.ContagionFactor);
    printf("\n");

    printf("How is %s Transmitted?\t\t(Sample: Airborne, Touch, Sex, Sneezing, etc.)\n",Dissarray.Disease);
    gets(Dissarray.Spread);
    fprintf(fptr,"Spread: %s\n",Dissarray.Spread);
    printf("\n");

    fflush(stdin);

    Dissarray.Fatalities=0;

    printf("On a yearly basis. What is the average Fatality count brought by %s?\t\t(How many have died to this disease? Sample:100000)\n",Dissarray.Disease);
    if(scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Fatalities)!= 1)
    {
      printf("This is not an appropriate number. Please enter appropriately.\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Fatalities);
    }
    fprintf(fptr,"Fatalities: %d\n",Dissarray.Fatalities);
    printf("\n");

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Has %s been known to evolve under any conditions?\n",Dissarray.Disease);
    printf("What is the Sensitivity?\t\t(Sample:Temperatures over 90 degrees OR None.)\n");
    gets(Dissarray.Sensitivity);
    fprintf(fptr,"Sensitivity: %s\n\n",Dissarray.Sensitivity);
    printf("\n");

    printf("This ends the entry of info into the file\n");
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Error! There is no file to write to. Please Create a file");`  1) this not the only reason a call to `fopen()` can fail.  2) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  3) when writing an error message about a C library function, also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The best way to handle such an error is to call `perror()` as it will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: BTW:  when calling `fopen()` with a mode of `"a+"`  if the file does not exist, it will be created

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);` Regardless of what visual studio allows, the C standard specifically states that a call to `fflush()` on a input stream is undefined behavior.  Suggest using: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: regarding: `gets(Dissarray.Disease);`  The `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and completely removed in the latest versions of the C language.  Suggest using `fgets()`  Note: this uses a different set of parameters

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\n");`  The `printf()` function is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest: `puts( "" );`

Comment: regarding: `if(scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Fatalities)!= 1)
    {
      printf("This is not an appropriate number. Please enter appropriately.\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Fatalities);
    }`  This only retries once to input a number.  Suggest using: `while( scanf("%d", &Dissarray.Fatalities) != 1)
    {
      puts("This is not an appropriate number. Please enter appropriately.");
      fflush(stdin);
    }`

Comment: what is the definition of the struct: `Dissarray`?

Comment: the structure of Dissarry is
    struct New{
        char Disease[100];
        int Lethality;
        char ContagionFactor[100];
        char Spread[100];
        int Fatalities;
        char Sensitivity[500];
    }Dissarray;

Comment: regarding: `if()`   This is unlikely to compile!   What are you trying to test at this point in the code?

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments.  Rather, edit the question

Comment: OT: BTW:  variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).   The struct tag name `New` is meaningless, even in the current context

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question about line numbering:

regarding:

```
int diseasenum=1;
```

change to:

```
static int diseasenum=1;
```

Then, before exiting the function:

```
diseasenum++;
```

Comment: And your homework is to figure out why that worked as your teacher will surely ask...